# React/Redux: Effectively change a component's corresponding state in Redux's tree

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I essentially have a similar hierarchy between my components and Redux state, represented below, where each component has a `id`, `name`, `details`, etc:

```
Redux hierarchy:
parent -> child1 -> element1
                    element2
                    element3
          child2 -> element1
                    element2

React hierarchy:
ParentComponent -> ChildComponent -> ElementComponent
```

Suppose I wanted to element2 of child1 to change its name, with it being reflected in the Redux state, how would I go about doing this efficiently?

What I want is to somehow create a link using the `id` of element2 of child1 and the `id` in the state so I can change the corresponding Redux state without doing a deep search inside the Redux store in order to change the corresponding state.

I could effectively create this using React's state model and have each component manage its own state but but since I need this state elsewhere, how would I tackle this in Redux state? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you could just go down a predicted object path but because the object path may be variable due to the nature of `element`s, I decided to use a combination of brute force and the predicted object path.

In this particular scenario `Parent` is the common node between all the `element`s so a brute force search for `id` would work well enough.

This reusable function would provide a brute force recursive search in the root node for each object and provide a callback to perform on each object.

```js
export const iterateNodes = (obj, callback) => {
    if (!obj) return undefined

    for (let property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property] != null) {
            if (obj[property].constructor === Object) {
                iterateNodes(obj[property], callback)
                callback(obj[property])
            } else if (obj[property].constructor === Array) {
                for (let i = 0; i < obj[property].length; i++) {
                    iterateNodes(obj[property][i], callback)
                    callback(obj[property][i])
                }
            } else {
                // console.log(obj[property])
            }
        }
    }
    return obj
}
```

*This was pulled from another StackOverflow question and modified a bit. I can't seem to find the source.*

Then you can create another function to modify the node with particular options. This snippet has `overwrite` options in case the whole object needs to be overwritten.

```js
export const modifyNodeById = (
    root,
    id,
    modification,
    options = {}
) => {
    if (!id) throw new Error('id not specified')

    return iterateNodes(root, node => {
        if (node.id === id) {
            if (options.overwrite)
                Object.getOwnPropertyNames(node).forEach(key => delete node[key])
            Object.assign(node, { ...modification })
        }
    })
}
```

> Import note: This function mutates the object.

State mutation should be 100% avoided so the easy way out for this one is just to use lodash's `cloneDeep` function to create a deep copy. You probably could optimize to copy only the needed branches in the state but unless your state is thicc, it probably isn't worth it.

So a final answer could be:

```
modifyNodeById(parent, 13, { isUnlocked: true })
```

To append the properties to the object node with `id: 13` starting the search under `parent`.